# Лучшая среда для разработки андроид приложений средствами JS + CSS + HTML ?

Tags: android

В какой среде программирования лучше всего учится и разрабатывать приложения для андроид средствами JS + CSS + HTML ? Adobe Air ?

Comment: а java вас чем не устраивает?

Comment: java я не знаю) а эти знаю)

Comment: неплохой повод изучить между прочим. Не всю же жизнь сидеть на html

Comment: Это будет выглядеть ужасно. Кроссплатформенная разработка средствами JS + CSS + HTML ни когда не догонит нативные приложения.     
Adobe AIR - неплохой вариант, работает на много быстрее и красивее, чем JS + CSS + HTML, но он использует ActionScript, а не JS + CSS + HTML.

Comment: Автор указал с помощью каких средств, а ему всё равно указывают что используй java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/titanium/) -
     открытая, расширяемая среда
     разработки для создания красивых
     нативных приложений работающих на
     различных мобильных платформах и
     операционных системах, включая iOS,
     Android и BlackBerry, а так же
     гибридные приложения и HTML5. Она
     включает в себя SDK с открытым
     исходным кодом с API для более чем
     5000 устройств и мобильных
     операционных систем, Studio - мощную,
     основанную на Eclipse среду
     разработки, Alloy - MVC-фреймворк и
     Cloud Services для готового к
     использованию бэкенда мобильных
     приложений. Так же в марте этого года
     вышла книга  [Appcelerator Titanium:
     Up and Running. Building Native iOS
     and Android Apps Using
     JavaScript](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025528.do).
- [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) - наиболее известная из этой четверки платформа. По Phonegap уже вышло столько книг, что перечислять их не имеет смысла.
- [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch) - платформа разработки мобильных приложений на JavaScript от Sencha. Их продукт [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) более известен и имеет много общего с Sencha Touch.
- [Enyo](http://enyojs.com/) - еще одна платформа подобного типа. В январе этого года вышла книга  [Enyo: Up  and Running. Build Native-Quality Cross-Platform JavaScript Apps.](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920027751.do)

Answer (score 2):

лучше учиться писать на нативных языках. для андроид это java, в качестве IDE сейчас уже лучше пользоваться Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Интересный вопрос)
Как на счет eclips + phoneGap ?